# How to Erase all Contents and Settings on macOS programmatically? (Wipe all User data)

Tags: macos, big-sur, monterey

I want to erase all contents and settings on MacOS through c++, objective C or Swift. Basically I want to mimic Remote Wipe without MDM. Is there any way by which I can achieve this or is it possible entirely through command line without User's interaction? I want to support this feature on macOS Big Sur onwards.

Comment: This *may* be possible just through a shell script, but specific questions about programming (*any platform Mac, Windows, Linux*) need to be taken over to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Big Sur is going to hard-stop you if anything you want is on the system volume. I'd be entirely surprised it would let you anywhere near the rest without explicit sudo permissions, which from 'remote' is going to need the current admin's credentials. A "Remote data wipe without user credentials" is more commonly known as a *virus*. What exactly is it you're trying to achieve & why don't the official methods cover your needs?

Comment: @Tetsujin We are trying to build MDM like solution without actually using MDM. We will carry the task name remotely. On local machine I have agent running with root privileges. So just want to know is it possible to wipe out Mac without user's intervention ?

Comment: macOS doesn't use root normally, & even if you enable it, it doesn't give you more permissions than any admin has. I think you're going about this the wrong way. Without an MDM running, any admin can just delete your script or override you, or just log you out & there's nothing you can do about it.